# Can't keep the php session more than 30 mins

Tags: php, apache, session

I tried following other posts to use these instructions at the begin of the script:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',24*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
session_cache_expire(24*60*60);
```

but always seeing session expires after 30 minutes. the `session_start()` is called after that instructions.

PS: I'm using an Ubuntu LAMP remote server.

Comment: call `session_start` before `session_cache_expire(24*60*60);`

Comment: Also, make sure the session cookie is set to expire after the desired amount of time. (Session cookie lifetime http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php)

Comment: I'm trying both the methods now. i'll keep you updated, thanks.

Comment: No, it doesn't works. I still lose my session before 24h. I've both tried the set_cookie_params and session_cache_expire after session_start.

Answer (score 0):

You have you change those configurations from the ini, otherwise they do not stay that way after the page has been executed, so therefore as the user continues using the website, they hit the `php.ini`'s session max lifetime: `session.gc_maxlifetime` 
you would have to edit php.ini to contain:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 86400
```